# How to export report from Google Analytics contain maximum rows

Tags: google-analytics, report

I exporting Google Analytics custom report from my GA account, IN email attachment I receiving only 10 row at time in report .
I also change the setting for Rows show from 10 to 5000 .then also receives only 10 rows.
Is any other setting required to receive report with maximum rows through  email .
Please help !

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Downloading as CSV is very limited from what I can see.    I wonder if they are still working on this feature it doesn't seem to be as complete as it could be.

You might want to consider using App Scripts to export the data into a Google Sheet this will then allow you to request what ever you want though the Google Analytics API.   Then you can download your sheet as a csv file.  That you can then insert into your database.

Which database are you using?

Comment: Thanks for reply, But after downloading the report i need to insert these records into my local db. So I prefer for xls or csv rather than pdf

Thanks,

Comment: Using Sql server 2008 db and C# app to process xls or csv file

Comment: I think it wouldn't it be easer to create a C# app to download your data and insert it directly.  You will loose the csv step that way.

Comment: Thanks, I will inform you back what will decide

Comment: If you want to test something that does what I'm talking about. I have created an application that does this already.  http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-import/